# Pandas convert timeframes to indexes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time

can you please suggest me an easy way to convert time periods to the corresponding indexes?

I have a function that picks entries from data frames based on numerical indexes (from 10th to 20th row) that I can not change. At the same time my data frame has time indexes and I have picked parts of it based on timestamps. How to convert those timestamps to the corresponding numerical indexes?

Thanks a lot
Alex

Adding some examples:

```py
small_df.index[1]
Out[894]: Timestamp('2019-02-08 07:53:33.360000')

small_df.index[10]
Out[895]: Timestamp('2019-02-08 07:54:00.149000') # instead of time stamps.
```

These are the time period I want to pick from a second data frame that has time indexing as well. But I want to do that with numerical indexing 
That means then
1. Find which numerical indexes correspond to the time period above

Based on the comment above this might be quite close on what I need:

```py
start=second_dataframe.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(small_df.index[1]))

end=second_dataframe.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(small_df.index[10]))

picked_rows= second_dataframe[start:end]
```

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Can you add some data sample with expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) if need position:

```
small_df.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp('2019-02-08 07:53:33.360000'))
1
```

EDIT: If values always matched, is possible get timestamp form first and extract second rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
start = small_df.index[1]

end = small_df.index[10]

picked_rows = second_dataframe.loc[start:end]
```

OrL

```
start=pd.Timestamp(small_df.index[1])

end=pd.Timestamp(small_df.index[10])

picked_rows = second_dataframe.loc[start:end]
```

Comment: start=second_dataframe.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(small_df.index[1]))
end=second_dataframe.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp(small_df.index[10]))
picked_rows= second_dataframe[start:end]

Is there a better way?

Comment: @AlexP - If values always matched, is possible get timestamp form first and extract second rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)